# Joint probability and Gaussian copula

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, joint-distribution, copula

I have $\Pr(A)=29\%$ and $\Pr(B)=10\%$, where $A$ and $B$ are two events which are not independent.

In fact, a correlation measure suggests they're correlated by $\rho=0.8$.

I would like to calculate $\Pr(A \cap B)$, that is the probability both of them occur.

Here is what I've done in R:

```
prA <- .29
prB <- .1
Sigma <- matrix(.8, 2, 2)
diag(Sigma) <- 1
qA <- qnorm(prA, 0, 1)
qB <- qnorm(prB, 0, 1)
library(mnormt)
pmnorm(x = c(qA, qB), mean = rep(0, 2), varcov = Sigma)
```

Is the result of such a code $\Pr(A \cap B)$ I'm looking for?

Comment: What does it mean for _events_ to be correlated? $\text{Pr}(A\cap B)$ can be _any_ number in $[0.0,0.1]$ with the possible exception of $0.29\times 0.1 = 0.029$ which would be the value of $\text{Pr}(A\cap B)$ if $A$ and $B$ were _independent_ events, a possibility that you have excluded.

Comment: If you are looking at $I_A$ the indicator random variable for the event $A$ and similarly $I_B$, then I do not think you can get the correlation between them greater than about $0.5216$, and that happens when $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are just two binary random variables with $P(A=1) = p$, $P(B=1) = q$ and $\rho$ their correlation coefficient known, we can easily estimate the full joint distribution of $A$ and $B$.

Let $P(A=1 \cap B = 1) = r$, then $P(A =1, B=0) = p - r$, $P(A =0, B=1) = q - r$, and $P(A = 0, B=0) = 1-p-q+r$. The only unknown is $r$.

Now $r$ can be computed by writing out the expression for the correlation coefficient,

$E[(A-p)(B-q)] = \rho \sqrt{p q (1-p)(1-q)}$

the left hand side of which can be written out in terms of $p$, $q$ and $r$. This equation can be solved to obtain $r$.

Of course, as Henry pointed out above, there may not be a solution for certain combinations of $p$, $q$ and $\rho$,

Comment: In fact, since $E[(A-p)(B-q)] = E[AB]-pq =r-pq$, the putative value of $r = P(A=1\cap B=1)$ is $$pq+\rho\sqrt{p(1-p)q(1-q)}=0.029 + 0.13612861565446\rho,$$ putative because the number thus computed might not be in the interval $[0,1]$.  In this instance, since the largest possible value of $r$ is $0.1$, $\rho$ cannot exceed $\approx 0.5216$ as pointed out by Henry. Since the smallest possible value of $r$ is $0$, $\rho$ cannot be smaller than $\approx -0.2130$ either.

Comment: I appreciate very much your answers, I'm studying them. Then my question would be: what am I really doing when I follow the steps which I've listed in my R code?